# (Java) Array element printing out application.class@xxxxxxx

Tags: java, arrays

I am printing out an element from an array. The array holds a (class) Card and each card consists of a string face(in this instance K) and a char(in this instance the spade).The project name is pokergames, the class is Card. Below is what is printing out:

pokergames.Card@26ffd553

Hint: I have tried converting the card using the toString() method and the output is them same as without it.

It should look like this: ♠K

Here is the coding I have used:

```
//create the 2 private attributes
private String face;
private char suit;

//constructor for card
public Card(String face, char suit)
{
    this.face = face;
    this.suit = suit;
}

//create the public function toString to add the face and suit
public String tostring()
{
    return face + suit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toString` method signature is wrong. It should be `toString` and not `tostring`.

To avoid a logical mistake while overriding a method, you should use `@Override` annotation to be sure that you are overriding the correct method. So your toString should ideally be like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return face + suit;
}
```

Comment: +1. This answer is correct. As a side note, the default implementation of toString() prints `className@Integer.toHexString(hashCode)` , thats why you get that output.

Comment: @TheLostMind Thanks for the valuable info, like it!